# Need help adding card elements to my Array List

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist, addition

```
package decks;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class hand {

private ArrayList<card> hand;
private card test;

public hand(){
    hand = null;
}

public void clear(){
    for (int x = hand.size() - 1; x >= 0; x--)
        hand.remove(x);
}

public void addCard(card c){
    hand.add(c);
}

public void removeCard(card c){
    if (hand.contains(c))
        hand.remove(c);
}

public void removeCard(int pos){
    hand.remove(pos);
}

public int getCardCount(){
    return hand.size();
}

public String toString(){
    String toReturn = "";
    for (card n : hand)
        toReturn += n + "\n";
    return toReturn;
}
```

}

> Alright so I have to make a card game for homework at my school, and so far we've made a card, deck, and hand class plus a runner. We built the decks and hands using Array Lists. I was trying to test it out by adding a card to the deck by using:

`pOne.addCard(test);`

> The only thing in the addCard class is:

```
public void addCard(card c){
    hand.add(c);
}
```

> This however, only returns an error, it never actually adds a card to the ArrayList hand. Any ways to fix this? PLease help

Comment: `"This however, only returns an error..."` -- What error are you seeing? And word of advice -- don't give your ArrayList the same exact name as your class; that's **way** too confusing. Follow Java naming rules and start the class name with a capital letter as well.

Answer (score 2):

You initialize the `List` to `null` in the constructor. Instantiate the `List` instead. Something like,

```
public hand(){
    // hand = null;
    hand = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Also, by convention, Java class names start with a capital letter. So, I would *prefer* classes `Hand` and `Card` (instead of `hand` and `card`). Finally, for `clear`, you can call [`List.clear()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#clear--) instead of using a loop.

Comment: ok I'll try instantiating it differently and changing the names, as for the 'List.clear()', we're not allowed to do that, as it's not allowed on the AP exam